# how to hide the global name space object in module base application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

how to avoid accessing name space object.

```
window.myApp = window.myApp || {};

myApp.Base.Controller = myApp.extend({});
myApp.Base.Model = myApp.extend({});
myApp.Base.View = myApp.extend({});
```

here i am attaching everything to the myApp and myApp will be avail in window object.

how can i hide myApp Object accessing from window level.

Comment: Wrap you code in selfexecuted function or set fields of this object to read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Człowiek Fin Śpiewak already suggested, you can wrap the code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function(){
  var myApp = {};
  myApp.Base.Controller = myApp.extend({});
  myApp.Base.Model = myApp.extend({});
  myApp.Base.View = myApp.extend({});
})();
```

I also suggest looking into [require.js](/questions/tagged/require.js)